# Why is link to gmail message from notification dropdown intermittent?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq, aquaris, m10

On BQ Aquaris-M10, gmails appear in the notification area drop-down (upper-right corner) turning the envelope green with e-mail headers shown below.

When I touch an individual e-mail to launch full-screen; sometimes it launches, sometimes the gmail symbol shakes signifying "no", sometimes it launches after several attempts.

Why the inconsistent response when, to me, it seems like consistent input?

Comment: You have to tap the actual gmail symbolic icon to open it. The shake is to inidicate that you need to tap it. I have never really got why it is like that as you would expect tapping anywhere in the notification would open it.

Comment: In some cases, I think I am on the symbol when it refuses to open. So, I guess that means it is finicky about the position of the tap, and I am not in the correct position, though I think I am?

Comment: yeah, i think i've had it a few times where it takes a few taps for it to actually activate. It's really not the best UX tbh. I believe they are currently re-designing and implementing the messaging inidicator so hopefully this will get addressed as well

Comment: Cool. Would you like me restate this as an answer, below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the answer above, you have to specifically tap the Gmail icon in the notification itself. This can be rather tricky if you have big fingers as it is a bit of a small icon. Also if you slide the notification to the right, the delete icon is shown. However, tapping this does not delete the email in question, rather it deletes the notification. this is not as useful as deleting the email from your client. I raised this a bit ago that if you click on any part of the notification, it should open the email. Also if you click the delete icon, this should delete the email not just the notification. To add to this, if you change your email client (say to Dekko) you cannot open it from the notification. When you click on the email icon, it will take you to the Gmail client and not Dekko to read your mail. If you remove the Gmail client, email notifications do not come through.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tap the gmail icon to open it, though you would expect tapping anywhere in the notification would open it. They are currently re-designing the messaging indicator. Sometimes, it takes a few taps for it to activate as it is sensitive to the position of the tap. [with thanks to Daniel Chapman]